# DialogFlow in frondend setting React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, fs, dialogflow-es

When I try to include the dialogflow SDK into my react app I get the following error.

[image: The error]

As I understand from what I've read this is because fs is a server-side module rather than a client-side module. But the documentation of the SDK imply that it is meant as a front-end SDK. So I hope we can get it to work.

Steps to reproduce

1. run in console create-react-app reporduce_issue
2. run in console npm install --save dialogflow
3. add import {SessionsClient} from 'dialogflow' to App.js

I hope this can be solved.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For front-end work you'll want to use the Dialogflow JavaScript Web SDK, which is available here on GitHub:

https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-javascript-client

You can install this via NPM using `npm install api-ai-javascript@2.0.0-beta.14`.

The package you are currently installing is in fact the node.js client, available here:

https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-nodejs-client-v2

Comment: I think you are correct in stating this, the question I have is if the javascript client also supports the dialog flow v2 api (which they suggest new projects should use). I can't check yet since I have the issue that importing import * as ApiAi from "api-ai-javascript"; throws the error './srces6/_build' in 'D:\workspace\chatbot_plugin\node_modules\api-ai-javascript. which im still strugling with

Comment: My issue was using using it as a normal dependency rather than a dev-dependency. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @DaanLuttik Did you manage to get it to work on client side (in your case React) by using it as a dev dependency?

Comment: No i did not manage to get it to work in the frontend. So Ive moved the computation to the backend